# Transition only apply to one type of change - CSS

Tags: css

In this code, if you resize your screen, it'll change its size smoothly and will take a second to get there.

```js
function f1(x) {
  x.classList.toggle('fade');
}
```

```css
.div {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: #e50;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1000ms;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='div' onmouseover="f1(this)" onmouseout="f1(this)">

</div>
```

I only want the opacity to change slowly like so. Everything else should change in *0s* as is default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the opacity value to transition explicitly:

```
 transition: opacity 1s
```

### Demo

```js
function f1(x) {
  x.classList.toggle('fade');
}
```

```css
.div {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: #e50;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s
}

.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='div' onmouseover="f1(this)" onmouseout="f1(this)">

</div>
```